# Portrait/Landscape Mode in Desktop Builds of Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 3d, game-development

Is there a way to rotate the screen in a Windows build of a game?

I've tried using `Screen.orientation = ScreenOrientation.X`, but it only works for mobile builds. I want to physically rotate the entire game and all UI elements, similar to how it works in mobile builds.

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Unity has a Q&A page that is very similar to stack overflow. Here is the answer to your question. - https://discussions.unity.com/t/is-it-possible-to-rotate-the-entire-screen-orientation/216271